# Need to convert method from Objective-C to just C in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I am working on iOS app that has a file of the form .mm, and contains code entirely in C.  I have the following blocks of code that I need to put inside this file:

```
void initAudioSession()
{
    BOOL success = NO;
    NSError *error = nil;

    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setActive:YES error:&error];


//the above code is the method where the block below goes in

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType:)
     name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];
```

which in turn calls the following method:

```
- (void)audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    AVAudioSessionInterruptionType interruptionType = [[[notification userInfo]
    objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
    if (AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan == interruptionType)
    {
    }
    else if (AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded == interruptionType)
    {
    }
}
```

Both blocks of code that I've posted above are in Objective-C, and I need to convert both of them to C, and put them inside the .mm file.  The problem is that I don't have a C background, and not sure what changes I need to make to do this.  One obvious problem I'm having is that the compiler is not recognizing the keyword `self`.  Why is it not recognizing `self`, and what should it be changed to in C?

Comment: First, AFAIK, it's not possible, since there is no C-wrapper for `NSNotificationCenter`, for instance. Second, why would you want that? *.mm files are OBjective-C++ files, they can handle this code perfectly.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish here?

Comment: My mistake.  How would I then convert the above to C++?  For example, the method above when I put in the .mm file gave me an error: Missing context for method declaration.  In turn this method is called by the block of code above it, which, when I put inside a method, gives me an error because it doesn't recognize the keyword "self".

Comment: @syedfa, well, the same questions apply here. What are you trying to accomplish? You can't access the `NSNotificationCenter` from a pure C++, whereas from Objective-C++ (*.mm files) you can use the code above as it is.

Comment: @FreeNickname  Then I guess my first issue is why is it not recognizing the keyword "self"?  Error message I'm getting is: "Use of undeclared identifier 'self'".

Comment: Actually, @kdhp solution actually might work, I didn't think about sending messages through C API. But, as we've just found out, the issue is different :) Give me a moment...

Comment: @syedfa, could you provide a context of the call to `NSNotificationCenter` please? Where is it called from?

Comment: @FreeNickname this is the method where it goes...

void initAudioSession()
{
    BOOL success = NO;
    NSError *error = nil;
    
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setActive:YES error:&error];

Comment: Can you explain why you are forced to use C and not just use Objective C, when you are clearly interfacing with Objective C?

Comment: The entire file is in Objective C++, and I don't know C++.  I know Objective-C, and I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: Well, `- (void)audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType:(NSNotification *)notification` is defined in some class, isn't it? Then an object of this class should be in the place of `self`.

Comment: In C there is no `self`.  What object are you trying to use as the observer?

Comment: @FreeNickname I see what you're saying.  If it's inside a class that is the .mm file, then self would simply be an object of that class type?

Comment: @FreeNickname it seems that the file it's in is meant to provide utility functions for the project.  Hence the file is called Utils.mm.

Comment: @syedfa, yes, you should replace `self` with an object of the class, which implements `- (void)audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType:(NSNotification *)notification`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write Objective-C code in C you have to use the C API for Objective-C, the headers can be found as [`<objc/objc.h>`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.1/runtime/objc.h), [`<objc/runtime.h>`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.1/runtime/runtime.h), and [`<objc/message.h>`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.1/runtime/message.h). You can call selectors that you get from `sel_registerName` with `objc_msgSend`, and get classes with `objc_getRequiredClass` and  `objc_getClass`. Note that I am listing the easiest ones to use, there are functions for everything needed to make Objective-C work.

Here is your second code block in this style. The magic numbers were found in the header file that cannot be read by C. Also note that code compiled from Objective-C code will probably be more efficient, because of value caching and things like that.

```
extern id *const AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey;
void audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType(id self, SEL _cmd, id notification) {
    SEL userInfo = sel_registerName("userInfo");
    SEL objectForKey = sel_registerName("objectForKey:");
    SEL unsignedIntegerValue = sel_registerName("unsignedIntegerValue");
    id tmpid = objc_msgSend(notification, userInfo);
    tmpid = objc_msgSend(tmpid, objectForKey, AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey);
    unsigned interruptionType = objc_msgSend(tmpid, unsignedIntegerValue);
    if (interruptionType == 1) {
        // AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan
    } else {
        // AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded
    }
}
```

It might be worth checking if your code can be ported to apples C audio API [**CoreAudio**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html), it would probably work better than any C conversion.

Comment: The OP's problem turned out to be a bit different, but as for his original question, your solution might work, I didn't think about sending messages via Objective-C C API. +1.